# Getting JSON Data from InAppBrowser IONIC 5

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, ionic5

I'm using the cordova in-app-browser plugin. One Page I get back is just a bunch of JSON-Data which i want to store inside my IONIC 5 Project. I could'nt figure out yet how to receive the Data and transfer it to the App yet with the Plugin. Is there such a possibility?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want use the data (JSON-data ) inside the app ?

Comment: Yes exactly I want tonuse it inside my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer data using `InAppBrowser` you can pass It by parameters, and also to receive the date you get it from parameters. Follows a small example:

Short way sending data on Page1.ts:

```
const dataToSend = `/${this.dataOne}/${this.dataTwo}`;
let finalUrl = `https://app-example.io` + dataToSend;
this.inAppB.create(finalUrl, '_system');
```

Receiving data on Page2.ts:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute
){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.actRoute.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
    console.log('Params => ', params);
    if (params) {
      let dataReceived = [params['params']['dataOne'], params['params']['dataTwo']];          
      console.log('dataReceived => ', dataReceived);
    }
  }
}
```

Please, adapt it to your code and variables as it is just a short example.

Comment: @Huxel Please, let me know if you still have doubt.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the code! I will try that in a few days and will let you know. Unfortunately the backend is still in development and does not yet give me the data. I just have a json file for testing which is why i asked. But thank you very much! I will let you know